# Kotlin: LinkedList Implementation

Tags: java, kotlin

Why does Kotlin not have a `LinkedList` implementation in the Kotlin Standard Library (stdlib)?

If I'm working with Kotlin in the JVM I'm using the Java `LinkedList` [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Is there an equivalent in the stdlib (in particular regarding Kotlin Native Development)?

Comment: Note that `kotlin.collections.ArrayList` is declared as a type alias of `java.util.ArrayList`, so you're not gaining a lot there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin does not have its own collections because it would be too difficult to maintain Java interoperability.  Instead, the Kotlin Standard Library just adds some extension functions to the Java collections to make them easier to work with.

To quote [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action):

> Why are there no Kotlin collections? Because using the standard Java collections makes it much easier to interact with Java code. You don’t need to convert collections one way or the other when you call Java functions from Kotlin or vice versa.

Comment: But LinkedList in Java is not a child of MutableList in Kotlin, and that's a problem

Comment: And for multiplatform it would be nice to have the common implementation